# Installing the xcode command line tool (via a pkg file) on a Linux server

Tags: linux, xcode, centos, xcode7

I would like to install the XCode Command Line Tools on my Centos Linux server. The downloadable file comes packaged as a .pkg, so I can't install it. I see it is Unix so I should be in luck to use it (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

How might I be able to know what files to take from my local machine to then add to my server? Or is there another way to install the tools?

Does anyone have any experience getting the xcode-select tools working on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Although current versions of `Mac OS/X` are `UNIX` based, you would be unable to install `Xcode Command Line Tools` without a Mac, also .pkg files are Mac installer files.

If you are wanting to develop Mac applications on your Linux system, you would not be able to compile the applications without all the required binaries for the build.

This could possibly be done using `gcc`, although would be very difficult to achieve this, and you would need to code in C++.